# Migrate old php site database to rails with legacy script and mantain old ids

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, legacy

I'm trying to migrate my old php website database (mysql) to a rails 3 app (mysql) by a rake legacy script like this:

> [How to migrate legacy PHP mysql data to new Rails data model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417332/how-to-migrate-legacy-php-mysql-data-to-new-rails-data-model)

but i have a problem:
- old table id's were lost because if i have a table with

id | field
1 | field_value
2 | field_value 2
4 | field_value 4

Using Model.create(....) it becomes:

id | field
1 | field_value
2 | field_value 2
3 | field_value 4

how can i migrate using Model.create(....) and mantaining old id's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: [Overriding id on create in ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431617/overriding-id-on-create-in-activerecord)

Also, consider just dumping and importing the whole database. You can make rails specific modifications to the data later with migrations.